# Rstudio is duplicating commands in the command line

Tags: r, rstudio

Having a weird problem in R that seems to have come out of nowhere... output in the RStudio terminal is repeated without me asking for it... i.e.,

```
> 3+4
> 3+4
[1] 7
[1] 7
```

Anyone else have this issue and have any ideas how to resolve it? I'm also wondering whether it's actually performing the commands twice (and slowing things down considerably!).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not much information here to diagnose this. Does the problem persist if you restart your system? If yes, you should take this to the RStudio support.

Comment: Same problem here. The error occurred for me after I updated Rstudio to 0.98.501.

Comment: same problem and I am using 0.99.486

Comment: Same problem in 0.99.491. Came out of nowhere.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem in Rstudio 0.98.501. I restarted the R session and it disappeared. It is running the same command twice, which can not only slow things down but give erroneous results if you are transforming an object into the same name.

Comment: Had same issue. When I looked at History tab in RStudio, it suggested that each command is only run once, and it's just the Console showing duplicate rows (in a rather unpredictable manner). Like you, I restarted session (Session > Restart R) and it got fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Uninstalling R-Studio (v0.98.484?) & reinstalling latest version (v0.98.507) seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the 0.98.507 version.

Restaring the Rstudio solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I too experienced the similar problem.
I was using R version 3.2.3 and RStudio Version 0.99.893, just restarted my session and it was gone :) :)