# RStudio Run command running twice issue

Tags: r, command, rstudio

I have been having an odd issue with RStudio.

When I use any command to run the script (so either Ctrl + R, Ctrl + Enter, or the actual Run command on RStudio) that command is run twice. I have been unable to find anything about this on the internet.

Has any of you ever come across this issue?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105723/rstudio-is-duplicating-commands-in-the-command-line#comment33533301_22105723

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200956676-R-Studio-console-duplicates-every-line-that-I-type

Comment: Oddly enough this has now stopped happening - without me doing anything specific about it...Thanks for the links anyways... although there doesn't seem to be an explanation as to why it happens, nor a solution...

Answer (score 4):

I restart RStudio. Change to another workspace and come back. The issue is fixed. So you can try to do that. Maybe can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the 0.98.507 version.

Restaring the Rstudio solved the problem for me.