# Why does RStudio duplicate my input?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm new with RStudio but I can't recall it doing this the last time I ran it. Whenever I enter a command in R, it runs the command in the console TWICE. For example typing '1+1' and enter:

```
> 1+1
[1] 2
> 1+1
[1] 2
```

Why does it do this?

Edit: Using RStudio 0.98.507. Apologies.

Comment: What are you using RStudio, RGUI, other ... ? And what R version ? We need more details...

Comment: Other people have pointed this out on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105723/rstudio-is-duplicating-commands-in-the-command-line) and on [RStudio site](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200956676-R-Studio-console-duplicates-every-line-that-I-type), it seems a random bug in RStudio... Solutions: update to the latest version, and if it happens again restart RStudio...