# R replacement function

Tags: r

Consider the following codes:

```
#rm(list=ls())
x <- 1:5
"[<-"(x, 2:3, value = 9:10)    
x
```

If I execute all the four lines at the same time, then x will be 1 9 10 4 5. If I execute the codes one by one, then in the end, x will be 1 2 3 4 5. What is the reason?

Comment: I see it as 1 9 10 4 5 either way.

Comment: How exactly are you executing these codes? I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Frank I tried again on another computer, x will be 1 2 3 4 5 either way. I think the replacement function should not be called directly.

Comment: @MrFlick execute all codes vs execute line by line

Comment: Maybe you're running a different version of R (mine's 3.2.5) or using some non-R layer, like Rstudio, that (if I understand correctly) messes with references. Nope, it's not Rstudio...

Answer (score 1):

If you execute

```
x <- 1:5
"[<-"(x, 2:3, value = 9:10)
```

you'll see the output resulting from the substitution:

```
1  9 10  4  5
```

However, the original value `x` will not be affected (you are not overwriting it)

Hence, if you execute `x`, you'll see its original value:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

If I run all the lines at the same time (I guess you're using RStudio), I'll see this (I think this is why you're asking for)

```
execute> x <- 1:5
execute> "[<-"(x, 2:3, value = 9:10)    
[1]  1  9 10  4  5
execute> x
[1]  1  9 10  4  5
```

I guess this is some kind of weird RStudio behavior (maybe similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105723/rstudio-is-duplicating-commands-in-the-command-line)), although, the value of `x` is not affected at all.

Note that it doesn't happen if you change the last line. E.g.

```
x <- 1:5
"[<-"(x, 2:3, value = 9:10)    
x <- 6:10

execute> x <- 1:5
execute> "[<-"(x, 2:3, value = 9:10)    
[1]  1  9 10  4  5
execute> x <- 6:10
execute>
```

EDITED

Running with R version 3.3.1 and RStudio Version 0.99.467.

Running the three lines changes the value of `x` to `1 9 10 4 5`. However, running the first line, and then both the second and the third, shows the right result (and the value of `x` is not affected)

```
execute> x <- 1:5
execute> "[<-"(x, 2:3, value = 9:10)    
[1]  1  9 10  4  5
execute> x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also think x should not change since there is no reassignment. R studio may somehow mess it up.

Comment: Can't confirm. The value of `x` is changed to `1 9 10 4 5` in any case (R v3.3.1) , whether I run the code in RStudio or in a shell. It also makes no difference if the lines are executed sequentially or at once.

Comment: Yeah, x changes to 1 9 10 4 5. Weird.

Comment: For me, it does make a difference. (R 3.3.1 and RStudio 0.99.467). If I execute the lines one by one, the final value of `x` is `1 2 3 4 5` . If I run all at once, `x` has a value of `1 9 10 4 5`. Could be a bug?

Comment: If I execute just the first line and then the two other lines, the result is correct (output of `1 9 10 4 5` and `x` is unchanged `1 2 3 4 5`).
The "bad result" happens when I run the three lines.

Comment: Dunno. I guess for now, just add the details for each session/environment where you can repro what the OP is seeing, so your answer at least helps it to be pinned down. I assume you mean that you tested it in both Rgui and Rstudio?

Comment: @JaimeCr Maybe. I am using RStudio 0.99.902, if you only change the second element in x ("[<-"(x, 2, 9)), the x will always be 1 2 3 4 5. For R (3.3.0), x may be 1 2 3 4 5 or 1 9 10 4 5, when you shut down and reopen R, the answer may change

Comment: @ZhaofengTang, yeah, I see the same result

Comment: @ZhaofengTang : With `"[<-"(x, 2, 9)`, "x" will never change because a new "double" "x" is created and assigned a "9" in its "2" position since you assign a "double" (9) to an "integer" ("x"). Using `9:10` you assign "integer"s to an "integer" so "x" should be overwritten. Why are you not using the `x[2:3] = 9:10` form?